# displaying boolean values from SQL Server as checkboxes

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Consider an Access front end and SQL Server 2008 backend. Access boolean datatype values are displayed as checkboxes on their forms. I want similar functionality except that my data backend is SQL Server 2008

One of my fields is a `0` or `1` in SQL Server, and when I display this data on my form in Access I want it to be displayed as a checkbox.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you showing multiple records at once in some sort of list or grid, or are you only showing one record at a time?

Comment: @little multiple records

Comment: What control are you using to display the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the control from the form if it's present.  Open the Toolbar and place a check box on the form.  Then change the check box Control Source to the SQL Server field.   Do not choose the Triple State option unless the field on SQL Server happily supports null values.